# How can I discover why no historical data was collected in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I only have Google Analytics data from last fall while the site has been live for 4 years.   The account has been created at least 4 years ago and for some reason no data was collected. I didn't make this website, I'm new to this project.

I'd like to find out **when** a Google Analytics account / property was created for a client and **who** did it.

I have access to an account, and a UA-XXXX-2 property only. No UA-XXXX-1 property.

I checked in the History of modifications and it only displays users management. I don't see neither an alert in the notifications archive that says the account does not collect any information.

Is the first user listed the creator of the account? If so, I'm missing some emails related to the creation of the property except one about the account being shared to this email address, 4 years ago. If no, how do you know who created the account?

So basically, I want to know **Who? What property? and When?** so that I can explain why there is data collected since only 6 months ago.

Does this information lie somewhere in Google Analytics?